# grunt ftp_push with more than one destination

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using `grunt-ftp-push` to upload my files to server.

I'm trying to register two different tasks - `BuildPushDev` and `BuildPush`, so I tried this:

```
   ftp_push: {
        dev:{
            your_target: {
                options: {
                    username: "xxx",
                    password: "yyy",
                    host: "server.com",
                    dest: '/site/wwwroot/dev/assets/'
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'dist/assets',                            
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        prod: {
            your_target: {
                 options: {
                    username: "xxx",
                    password: "yyy",
                    host: "server.com",
                    dest: '/site/wwwroot/dev/assets/'                     
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'dist/assets',                            
                    }
                ]
            }

        }
    }

grunt.registerTask('buildPush', [
    'build',
    'ftp_push:prod'
]);
grunt.registerTask('buildPushDev', [
    'build',
    'ftp_push:dev'
]);
```

but it's not working: and I'm getting `You did not specify all the requirements` error.

What am I doing wrong - or what alternatives can I use to register different tasks here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target definition is duplicated - there's no need for `your_target` key. `dev` and `prod` **are** your targets.

Simply remove it and "pull" the rest up:

```
ftp_push: {
  dev:{
    options: {
      username: "xxx",
      password: "yyy",
      host: "server.com",
      dest: '/site/wwwroot/dev/assets/'
    },
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'dist/assets',                            
      }
    ]
  },
  prod: {
    options: {
      username: "xxx",
      password: "yyy",
      host: "server.com",
      dest: '/site/wwwroot/dev/assets/'                     
    },
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'dist/assets',                            
      }
    ]
  }
}
```